# Error while trying to do sudo apt-get upgrade

Tags: raspbian, apt, update

E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove:4: Extra junk after value

Comment: Looks like there is some garbage in  /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove. Please provide the file contents.

Comment: I have ho clue how you manage to destroy the contents of this file. It should be a readable file: My starts with

APT
{
  NeverAutoRemove
  {
 "^firmware-linux.*";
 "^linux-firmware$";
  };

  VersionedKernelPackages
  {
 # linux kernels

Comment: can i change the content of the file?

Comment: Yes, just copy the file from a clean system.

Comment: @Hamza.Engineer please edit the question and do not put the requested information in the comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @framp said, just copy the file from a clean system.

Here's my /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove, from an up-to-date raspbian stretch:

```
APT
{
  NeverAutoRemove
  {
    "^firmware-linux.*";
    "^linux-firmware$";
  };

  VersionedKernelPackages
  {
    # linux kernels
    "linux-image";
    "linux-headers";
    "linux-image-extra";
    "linux-signed-image";
    # kfreebsd kernels
    "kfreebsd-image";
    "kfreebsd-headers";
    # hurd kernels
    "gnumach-image";
    # (out-of-tree) modules
    ".*-modules";
    ".*-kernel";
    "linux-backports-modules-.*";
        # tools
        "linux-tools";
  };

  Never-MarkAuto-Sections
  {
    "metapackages";
    "contrib/metapackages";
    "non-free/metapackages";
    "restricted/metapackages";
    "universe/metapackages";
    "multiverse/metapackages";
  };

  Move-Autobit-Sections
  {
    "oldlibs";
    "contrib/oldlibs";
    "non-free/oldlibs";
    "restricted/oldlibs";
    "universe/oldlibs";
    "multiverse/oldlibs";
  };
};
```

If it happens again, you might need to re-burn raspbian onto your sd card. If it *still* happens again, it might mean your sd card is corrupt.